# How to write the year in the reference list in bold when using natbib?

Tags: natbib, bold

I am using the [PhD thesis template by Sunil Patel](http://www.sunilpatel.co.uk/thesis-template/) (version 1.2) with Texmaker/MiKTeX on Windows 7.

The template uses the `natbib` package with the style `unsrtnat`. 
Now I want the reference list to appear a little differently: 
For articles, instead of the style

> 62(1):1-20, 1991

I want it to look like this:

> 62(1), 1-20, **1991**.

My problem is, if I test the command `\textbf{blabla}` e.g. in the article title, it works fine. But when I use

```
year = {\textbf{1991}}
```

and compile the document, it gives out a whole lot of weird errors, including "improper alphabetic constant" "Missing = for \ifnum" and "Missing number, treated as zero" all of them repeatedly. Trying to set it back by resetting the bibliography file to

```
year = {1991}
```

does not work.

What happened??

PS: I cannot change anything in the `.bst` file because of limited authorization for the program files (no administrative rights, thanks to the IT at the institute...).

For the exchange of the colon with a comma, I haven't even started to try to fix it yet. The bold-problem is already enough for my nerves...

Comment: You need to make changes to a copy of `unsrtnat.bst` with a different name. Doing changes like that is annoying, even for experienced user. I advice you to use package `biblatex` instead. The recent version of the template at latex-temmplates.com uses it as well. Please do *not* use the template put together by Sunil. It is not recommended and gave me grieve and sorrow so many many times :-(

Comment: You can download the current version of  [`unsrtnat.bst`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/unsrtnat.bst) from CTAN save it under a different name and modify it an then use the modified file in the `\bibliographystyle` statement. You should not get into permission trouble doing that.

Comment: Making changes to the .bst file does not work on my office computer, as mentioned in the PS. 
Do you have a recommendation on which template to use from latextemplates.com for a beginner to write a PhD thesis? I want it to look nice but I am not tooo picky about the details. The template should not be too complicated, that is the most important. 
It seems that the first one of the Phd templates on the website is the one that Sunil Patel modified. Is the original better than Sunil's version?
Big thx!

Comment: @Tina Sunil has the original and the code is a mess. Believe me, i can tell. The one on LaTeX-templates got an update recently, but to be honest ... I might be the last person on earth to ask about template advice. If you wanna use it, use the new one. Don't look at the coding in the example file, it is horrible and will be fixed within a few days. Ignore my name inside the thing, it is spelled incorrect and will be removed as well.

Comment: and by the way, don't forget to ping us using the `@` sign. @moewe